# Select photo while keep the order

Tags: javascript

I have a list of photo on the page, each have an unique id, user can click on them to toggle select the photo, when they click the submit button, I need to send the array of selected photo ids to the back end, in the order that the photo was selected.

I think that the fastest way to track if a photo is selected is to use an object that use photo id as key, like:

```
var selected = {
    "6272861": true,
    "6272888": true
}
```

when the user unselect a photo, I just need to `delete selected["6272861"]`.

But this will ignore the order, if I use an array to keep the selected photos:

```
var selected = ["6272861", "6272888"];
```

then when I need to unselect a photo, I have to loop through the array and delete the item.

Is there better ways? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some JavaScript that does what you say:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    "use strict";

    var imgClick = function (elemSelected, elemThis) {
        var idIndex;
        if ((idIndex = imgSelected.indexOf(elemThis.id)) === -1) {
            imgSelected.push(elemThis.id);
            elemThis.className = "selected"
        } else {
            imgSelected.splice(idIndex, 1);
            elemThis.className = "unselected";
        };
        console.log(elemSelected);
    }

    var imgDiv = document.getElementById("imgDiv");
    var imgChildren = imgDiv.children;
    var imgElements = [];
    var imgSelected = [];
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < imgChildren.length; i += 1) {
        imgElements.push(imgChildren[i]);
        imgChildren[i].addEventListener("click", function () {imgClick(imgSelected, this)});
    }
});
```

Here is the associated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="imageSelect.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    img.unselected {
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    img.selected {
        border-color: red;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-style: solid;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="imgDiv">
    <img class="unselected" id="img01" src="intrepidWidgets.ico" title="Unselected"/>
    <img class="unselected" id="img02" src="300px-Java_logo_svg.png" title="Unselected"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link that discusses the indexOf property of the Array global object.  It may have compatibility problems with Internet Explorer before IE 9, but they have code to fix that:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Here is a link to the working code. You need to open the console to see the resulting log (press F12 in Chrome):

http://www.quirkscode.com/flat/forumPosts/imgSelect/imageSelect.html

MDN also discusses addEventListener (search for that element name).  It is the preferred way now of adding event listeners, but has compatibility issues with IE < 9:

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to already know, objects do not keep the order so if the order is important, then you will want to use an array.

You can add an item to the end of the array with:

```
selected.push("6272898");
```

You can remove an item with a simple function:

```
function removeSelected(item) {
    for (var i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (selected[i] === item) {
             selected.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This searches the array from back to front so when an item is removed, we don't have to correct/change the loop index.